# ANTLR java How get token from tree nodes or sort nodes

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, antlr, antlr4

I have problem with ANTLRv4. I need to sort alphabeticly nodes in Antlr parsing tree.

Klas with ANTLR implementation :

```
public class Tokenizer {

public void tokenizer(String code, String path) {

        ANTLRInputStream in = new ANTLRInputStream(code);
        Java8Lexer lexer = new Java8Lexer(in);                     
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);   
        Java8Parser parser = new Java8Parser(tokens);
        parser.setBuildParseTree(true);        
        ParserRuleContext t = parser.compilationUnit();
        ParseTree tree = t;         

        System.out.println("Sciezka0: " + tree.getChild(0).getChild(0).getChild(0).getChildCount());           
        System.out.println("Sciezka1: " + tree.getChild(0).getChild(0).getChild(0).getChild(0));
        System.out.println("Sciezka2: " + tree.getChild(0).getChild(0).getChild(0).getChild(1).toStringTree());
        System.out.println("Sciezka3: " + tree.getChild(0).getChild(0).getChild(0).getChild(2).toStringTree());
        System.out.println("Sciezka4: " + tree.getChild(0).getChild(0).getChild(0).getChild(3).toStringTree();         


    }      
}
```

And tree what i need to sort : https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIqbx.jpg

I had idea to create new Tree-data class and copy recursive children from Antlr tree to ArrayList, then sort Array and addChildren to new Tree. 
But i have problem at start of this challange. I tried a lot of method from ParseTree class to get node from ANTLR tree and i always get something like this [794 790 785 728] or whole tree when i use .toString() method. 
Please help me and tell me how can i copy tree to my new Tree.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is almost correct.  You were on the right track.

The way I would continue it is:  Using the Listener class and a data structure like a List, simply record *either* the `Enter` or `Exit` event for each parser rule as you traverse the tree with a walker.  Then, once in the handler for the rule, as you say, recursively iterate through the various subtrees until you reach terminals (nodes with no children), adding them to the list.  You will likely have duplicates from any non-trivial input.

De-duplicate the list when done, or copy the list to another *sorted* list, checking for duplicates as you go and I think you're done.

Comment: Thank You for answer.
I implemented listener and walker and i think it works, but still he dont return to me any names or number of one node where he actualy is.

He gives me something like this http://imgur.com/a/JE5TC

My implementation of listener is simply for now : 
public class AntlrJava8Listener extends Java8BaseListener {
 
   
    @Override public void enterEveryRule(@NotNull ParserRuleContext ctx) {
     System.out.println(ctx.getStart());
     
    } 

If i use ctx.getText() he return me a lot of white lines

Comment: i dont understand what this table of number mean, i think its table of tokens or rules but how can i read this . Ofc its table for the same tree like i show you in my first post